# Absolute paths and disable hotlinking

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I use absolute paths for my `<img>` and `<audio>` tags, and I disable hotlinking. Does this stop pirates from stealing my content? I am most worried about them making a clone site.

They can always take screenshots and record directly from the soundcard, but other than that, are they able to steal large amounts of the content if I use the above mentioned tactic? Am I wasting my time trying to protect my stuff?

Comment: Absolute paths will in **no** way stop your content from being stolen

Comment: path structure has absolutely NOTHING to do with hotlinking. whether you say "drive to 123 main street", or "turn left at the 2nd cross roads", you'll STILL end up at the same location.

Comment: and if you awnt your content to be viewable by people over the web, then by definition it HAS to be available over the web, and there is absolutely **NO** difference, to the server, between "download to play" and "download to save". The bytes get transferred, regardless of how they'll be used on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively wasting your time trying to protect stuff. If an image or audio is serve-able to the web and legit users can see it, there's no way to stop them from downloading the files. Better off spending time making a better product. Of course things like games need anti cheat mechanisms, and some level of protection. But fighting piracy is a losing battle.

Comment: Thanks. I am making a series of small games for my site. So there is no way to protect it? What will big companies do when flash is gone? For example, PowToon uses flash but soon they will be forced to migrate to HTML5. What can the company do to protect their product?

Comment: Flash isn't safe from this either. You can download the SWF file and host it yourself. SWF files can be reverse engineered, so nothing is really safe. Really what protects you hear is legal action. Get your content copyright protected. If you find someone who has taken your game and re-hosted it, send them a DCMA takedown notice. Now one thing you can do is have a paywall infront of the games. Meaning no one can access the game pages without having a paid account. This obviously makes them less likely to be stolen, but also you restrict the # of users you can have.

Comment: Think about music piracy. Still very much a thing, but a lot of bands realized they can't fight it. People share the music in the end. So many have just changed their model. They give away music, or sell it for "name a price". Others use bandcamp to set a minimum price. Large fans can give more if they wish (I have definitely have). Really you just need to offer a good product, so people don't want to pirate it.